# how link a swf file with a image click event

Tags: html, css, flash

i want create a simple video gallery , where many images show in tables and when we click on any image related swf file play on that place..
here is my swf file -

```
<embed src="intro.swf" height="200" width="200">
```

i tried this but not work-

```
 <a href=<embed src="intro.swf" width="200" height="200">
<img border="0" src="5.jpg" width="340" height="185"><p>If you cannot see this, your computer doesn't support the format</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Is your file pathfor intro.swf is good and have enough permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the embed tag

```
<embed src="helloworld.swf">
```

And you can see the working demo from [w3schools here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed) .

The reason you can't open may :

1. You may given the file path as wrong
2. You may given wrong permissions to the folder that contains the .swf file